# SQL Get certain value form two tables and make result set multiple rows

Tags: java, sql

I have two tables:

```
TABLE 1
name age year
John 20 2001
Amy 21 2002

Table 2 
name age year
John 20 2001
Kal 21   2000


SELECT * FROM Table1 AND Table2 WHERE name = 'john';
```

I tried using the statement above but it would not work.

I need the statement to return all the tables that have the word john in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `union all`:

```
select name, age, year
from table1
where name = 'John'
union all
select name, age, year
from table2
where name = 'John'
```

Comment: does this return all the entrys with john n it?

Comment: @Juansdk . . . It returns all the rows from both tables where the name is `'john'`.